# normalize a matrix along one specific dimension

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a matrix of shape `[1000,500]`, and I would like to normalize the matrix along the second dimension. Is the following implementation right?

```
def norm(x):
    return (x - np.mean(x)) / (np.std(x) + 1e-7)

for row_id in range(datamatrix.shape[0]):
    datamatrix[row_id,:] = norm(datamatrix[row_id,:])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation would indeed normalize along the row-axis (I'm not sure what you mean by second dimension as rows are usually the first dimension of matrices, and numpy starts with dimension 0). You don't need to include the colon as it's implicit that you want all the rows.

Do remember to use the `float32` dtype in your datamatrix as opposed to a integer dtype as it doesn't do automatic typecasting.

A more efficient, or clean implementation might be to use `sklearn.preprocessing.normalize`.

But be aware that you're using standard score normalization which assumes your dataset is normally distributed.

Comment: Hi Kasper, thanks. If the data set is not normally distributed, what are other options. Generally, when building machine learning models, we usually normalize them before feeding them to the model.

Comment: @user288609 That depends on how your data is distributed. It's sometimes possible to transform the data to become normally distributed.